# Массив $_POST не содержит значений

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите разобраться почему не выводятся значения

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE users_id ='".intval($_COOKIE['id'])."' LIMIT 100";
$shopdata = mysql_query($query);

// Так как запрос возвращает несколько строк, применяем цикл
while($author = mysql_fetch_array($shopdata))
{
echo "<h1>".$author['name_of_shop']."</h1>
     <input name='".$author['shop_id']."' type = 'text' maxlength=2
            size = 3 value =".$author['size_of_discount'].">&nbsp;";

// Ниже то, что не работает корректно
    $q = mysql_real_escape_string($author['shop_id']);
    $m = $_POST[$q];
    echo "<h2>".$m."</h2>";
}
?>
```

По идее, `$m` должен выводить то, чем заполнен `value` в `input`, но вместо этого выводит только тег `h2`.
Помогите пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Массив $_POST содержит в себе данные отправляемые пользователем методом post при обращении к данной странице. Вы эти данные отправляете из браузера открывая страницу с этим кодом?

Comment: возпользуйтесь функцией отладки кода var_dump($_POST) и посмотрите есть ли в массиве _POST данные. И прекратите использовать mysql_query! В php для работы с БД есть более надежные инструменты для этого (PDO или mysqli)

Answer (score 1):

Массив `$_POST` заполняется только в том случае, если скрипт получает POST-запрос. Как правило, такой запрос отправляется либо AJAX, либо через HTML-форму, в атрибут `method` которой передано значение 'POST'

```
<form method='POST'>
    ...
    <input type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```